# How to create list picker and how to add items in it in window phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to create list picker control and how to add items in listpicker in window phone 7?

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth
and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), both in your project's list of references, and in your XAML (as a XML namespace, example named "toolkit")

Then add the listpicker where you want it with . Then either use [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), or set the ItemsSource directly in the C# code for your page.

But as you been told **many times before** the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) comes with examples of how to do this. You should consider reading those examples. You asked the same question in what, 3-4 different posts now? When are you going to learn that you'll not get a full solution on a silverplate on Stack Overflow. You're going to get advice, links we want you to read, and examples we want you to study. When you're ignoring all of this, and just repeating your questions, eventually nobody is going to bother answering you anymore.